# Problems with @Transactional and JerseyTest on Linux or Mac but not on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, hibernate, transactional, grizzly

We use jersey test with grizzly2 to run acceptence tests against mocked REST resources. On my windows machine everything's fine. But another developer with his Mac is getting the same error as our Jenkins (on Linux):

```
INFO: Creating Grizzly2 Web Container configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
02.08.2012 09:46:36 org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
SEVERE: Failed to start listener [NetworkListener{name='grizzly', host='localhost', port=9998, secure=false}] : java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Obviously we checked that this is not the case: No other process is using 9998..

I've been tracking the problem down to a single test , that is using @Transactional in combination with extending JerseyTest:

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:context-test.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TestPage extends JerseyTest {

    public TestPage() throws Exception {
        super("", "", "path.to.package");
    }

    // init database to be rolled back after test
    // ...

    // test that calls a controller requiring database access and then sends a request to a mock REST resource.
    // ...
}
```

So, the questions here are: Why not on windows? And what's wrong with using @Transactional.

**edit2**
It seems @Transactional is creating a proxy, this might be a problem..?! [See here](http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2012-02/message/144)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, make sure that you are not overRiding the tearDown() method in your TestPage test. If you have something to tear down, do it using a another method customTearDown() and annotate it with @After.

JerseyTest also uses the same method name tearDown() and the container never gets shut down if we override it.